# Pregnant before marriage

Tags: sex

As-salamu alaykum I have question to ask a scholar

its personal I couldn’t ask anyone please reply to me I did major sin may Allha forgive me I got pregnant last year and we decided to not tell anybody me and my boyfriend we got married everyone was happy the family friends now I had the baby but I have this feelings that there’s something wrong with my marriage do we have to do another Meher and how should we do plz help

Comment: Please read the disclaimer to the right. This is not a fatwa site and we do not give personalized verdicts. Answering whether or not a particular marriage was valid requires details which are absent from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you married your boyfriend with whom you established physical relations and got pregnant without wedlock doesn't mean that you didn't sin.

You sinned!

The only way to get rid of sin is -

1. to repent and to beg the mercy of Allah
2. to not repeat the same mistake again

> ***How do you know that you are going through true repentance?***

From my own experience (not necessarily the same sin you are talking about) -

1. You will feel terribly ashamed
2. whenever you will recall this incident, it will make you deeply sad and depressed
3. sometimes you will cry, and sometimes you will feel like slapping your face

In my case, I had to seek psychiatric care.

Answer (score 0):

You sinned. To hide your sin, you married.

Assuming that marriage was conducted properly, it should be valid.

There is only part which is missing. You need to repent before Allah. The repentance should towards Allah alone. There is no need to reveal your sins to anyone else.